# macOS - How do I change cert trust state from command line?

Tags: macos, keychain, certificate

My workflow involves changing a cert installed in the system's trust states between 'Use Custom Settings' and 'Never Trust' (see the Keychain Access screenshot below).
[image]

How do I do this from command line?

Answer (score -2):

Two hints:

- [security](https://ss64.com/osx/security.html)
- [requirements](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176)

Good luck!

Comment: If anyone can flesh this out with words to document / explain the links and how they fully answer the question at hand, that may turn this answer around and help others and the poster. Nothing yet addresses the command line aspect of the question specifically.